# I am trying to add single name in SQLite database of Android, but it adds multiple entries with same name

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to add one contact in database of android but it add multiple entries with same name.

```
//Function to add single name/group name in database class
    public void createGroup(GroupsDetail gd){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // put values in database
       values.put(group_NAME , gd.getName());
       db.insert(table_Group , null , values);
       // close database transaction
       db.close();
}

//Function to get all names/group names in database class
   public List<GroupsDetail> getallcontacts(){
       List<GroupsDetail> groupList = new ArrayList<GroupsDetail>();
       String query = "SELECT * From " + table_Group;
       //get referance of ContactAS database
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
       GroupsDetail group = null;
       if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            group = new GroupsDetail();
            group.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            group.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            groupList.add(group);
          }while(cursor.moveToNext());  
    }

    return groupList;   
}

//Code of main class 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

 public class Groups extends Activity{
 Button Addgroup,Delgroup;
 ListView groupnames;
 GroupsDetail gd;
 ArrayList<String> listItems;
 List<GroupsDetail> gdlist;
 Groupsdb gdb;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.groups);

    Addgroup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addgroup);
    Delgroup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deletegroup);
    groupnames = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listofgroups);
    groupnames.setLongClickable(true);

    gdb = new Groupsdb(this);
    listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    gdlist = new ArrayList<GroupsDetail>();

    gd = new GroupsDetail("Family");

    gdb.createGroup(gd);
    gdlist = gdb.getallcontacts();

    for(GroupsDetail cn : gdlist){
        listItems.add(cn.getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.text, listItems);
    groupnames.setAdapter(adapter);

     }

}

 //code of GroupDetails class

  public class GroupsDetail {

        private String Name;
        private int id;

public GroupsDetail(){}

public GroupsDetail(String name){
    super();
    this.Name = name;
}

public GroupsDetail(String name, int i){
    super();
    this.Name = name;
    this.id = i;    
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(int i){
   this.id = i; 
}

public String getName(){
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.Name = name;
}

  public String toString(){
    return "Group [id = " + id + ", Name = "+ Name + "]";  
      }
}
```

Comment: use `db.insertWithOnConflict` in place of `db.insert`

Comment: Abhishek Patel can you kindly tell me the arguments for this method ? Thanks for help !.

Comment: refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inserting multiple times.
If you insert only one record it is giving only one record.
If you close and open the app again it gives two records(inserting multiple)
I have attached working example
Please check once
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v3ucmaccyvyztm/Sample_2.zip?dl=0

Create table like

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

        String newTableQueryString = "create table " +
                TABLE_groups +
                                    " (" +
                                    TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                                    TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text, " +
                                    "UNIQUE ("+TABLE_ROW_ONE+") ON CONFLICT REPLACE" +
                                    ");";

        db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);
    }
```

and insert like

```
public void createGroup(GroupsDetail gd){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // put values in database
       values.put("group_name" , gd.getName());
       db.insertWithOnConflict("groups", null, values,  SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
       // close database transaction
       db.close();
}
```